Suppose $a_n \in (0,1)$, then prove that $na_n \to \infty \iff (1-a_n)^n \to 0$
Suppose $a_n \in (0,1)$, then prove that $na_n \to \infty \iff (1-a_n)^n \to 0$.
Assume $na_n\to \infty$, then we have
$$(1-a_n)^n \leq e^{-na_n} \to 0$$
where we use $1+x \leq e^x$ and plug in $x = -a_n$.
But I don't know how to do the other direction. Any hints?

Do the contrapositive.  Assume $na_n \not \to \infty$.  That means there is a $D$ where we can find an infinite number of $n$ where $na_n < D$.  Show that means there are there is constant $C > 0$ so that there are an infinite number of $n$ where $(1-a_n)^n >C$. (Hint: Let $C = e^{-D}$).  That shows $(1-a_n)^n \not \to 0$.  (BTW, I'm not really following your argument.)

@fleablood That's nice! For your last comment, do you mean my proof of $(1-a_n)^n \to 0$?

@efsdfmo12 sorry if this is an obvious question, but how is your inequality there derived?

@msantama I add some explanation to make the inequality more clear.

Hmm.... three people chose to prove $\Leftarrow$ vie contrapositive.  I wonder if directly would have been significantly more obscure.  I guess if $b_n = \frac 1n$ we have $ =\lim(1-b_n)^n =\frac 1e > 0 =\lim (1-a_n)^n$ so eventually $b_n=\frac 1n$ is significantly smaller than $a_n$ so $na_n$ is "significantly growing" and $na_n \to \infty$.  I'd have to break out my books for the exact definitions and theories to put the concept and to justify it.  Still, sometimes stating an iff as if/cont ("B is true if A is, and false if A isn't") cant be emotionally satisfying.

@fleablood Right. At the beginning I also tried to prove it directly. $(1-a_n)^n \to 0$ is equivalent to $n\ln (1+\frac{a_n}{1-a_n}) \to \infty$. So, I thought maybe I need to find some inequalities to bound $\ln (1+x)$ an expect we can get $na_n$ on the right hand side. What I could get is $n\frac{a_n}{1-a_n} \to \infty$. But I failed to get the final answer.

If $na_n\not\to\infty$, then we have a subsequence $a_{n_i}$ where $n_ia_{n_i}<V$ for some constant $V$, and $a_{n_i}\to 0$.
Thus $$(1-a_{n_i})^{n_i}=(1-a_{n_i})^{\frac 1{a_{n_i}}(n_i a_{n_i})}>(1-a_{n_i})^{\frac 1{a_{n_i}}V}\to e^{-V}.$$
Thus $$(1-a_n)^n\not \to 0.$$

To prove the $\Rightarrow$: Suppose that $na_{n}\rightarrow\infty$.
Let $M>0$ be arbitrary, then there exists $N$ such that $na_{n}\geq M$
whenever $n\geq N$. For $n\geq N$, we have that $(1-a_{n})^{n}\leq(1-\frac{M}{n})^{n}$.
It follows that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-a_{n})^{n}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{M}{n})^{n}=e^{-M}.$
Since $M>0$ is arbitrary, we further let $M\rightarrow\infty$ and
conclude that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-a_{n})^{n}\leq0$. Clearly
$(1-a_{n})^{n}\geq0$, so $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-a_{n})^{n}\geq0$.
Lastly, $\limsup_{n}(1-a_{n})^{n}=\liminf_{n}(1-a_{n})^{n}=0$ implies
that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-a_{n})^{n}=0$.

To prove the $\Leftarrow:$ Prove by contradiction. Suppose that $na_{n}\not\rightarrow\infty$,
then $\liminf_{n}na_{n}=c<\infty$. Choose a subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})$
from $(a_{n})$ such that $n_{k}a_{n_{k}}\rightarrow c<c+1$. Choose
$K$ such that $n_{k}a_{n_{k}}<c+1$ whenever $k\geq K$. For $k\geq K$,  $(1-a_{n_{k}})^{n_{k}}\geq(1-\frac{c+1}{n_{k}})^{n_{k}}$,
so $0=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(1-a_{n_{k}})^{n_{k}}\geq\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{c+1}{n_{k}})^{n_{k}}=e^{-(c+1)}$,
which is a contradiction.
